# Visual Studio 2015 Debugging vs Not Debugging Views

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

When you are working in visual studio you have your windows docked in certain places. When you debug you get a different context and visual studio allows you to set new places for your windows that it will remember. How do I get rid of that? I don't really want the second context. I don't want my windows jumping around.

Comment: Really? Developing is much different from debugging, so the views should adapt to that. What if you just rearrange the windows while in debug view so they look the same? It should remember the layout for next time

Comment: @ThomasWeller I do most of my developing when the app is running. This allows me to see my program and make the changes I want. If I am truly 'debugging' then I will open my Call Stack and such manually, but for the majority of the time I don't actually need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some debug windows were opened in default if your app is in debug mode like the Call Stack/local or others. Like Weller's suggestion, if you debug it for the second time after you close certain debug windows, it would not show them again.

[image]

I often use the default VS settings in my side. If some windows' location were changed by myself, I often use the option "Reset windows layout" under Window menu of VS IDE, so it will go back to the default location.

So you couldn't close all of them for all apps like the new app or others, one workaround is that you could close them manually like Weller's suggestion, another is that like my suggestion, use the default settings even if you could still see them, at least, the locations of all windows are not changed:)

[image]